# Вызов функции в if

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть

```
tut = int(input("Нажми 1"))
if tut == 1:
   print (R1)
```

Далее я хочу чтобы если ввести иной символ сразу запускался цикл `while`. Как мне это сделать?

И как сделать так чтобы пользователю нужно было нажать на конкретную клавишу, если он нажал не на ту клавишу выскакивала через `print` мол ошибка

Comment: if tut == 1:   print (tut) else: print('ne tut') ([вот, почитайте про [if Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements))

Answer (score 1):

Поместите все в цикл и не выпускайте из него пока не получите правильный ответ:

```py
while True:
    tut = int(input("Нажми 1"))
    if tut == 1:
        print ("R1")
        break
    else:
        print("error")
        continue
# Продолжение программы
```

P.S. И еще лучше оставьте "1" строкой тогда при вводе буквы у вас не будет крашится вся программа.